# (Stuck!) Django operational error: table "accounts_profile" already exists

Tags: python, django

Long story short. I tried to add a custom user model to my existing project and realized too late  that it wouldn't work well as I already started my project. Then I deleted the migrations, all the customusermodel  related codes and re ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Nothing wrong showed up at this point.

Then I started following a tutorial to create a profile model to link to the default User model and everything was fine until I wanted to create a new superuser and django showed this error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user`.

Then, I saw similar errors online and and followed one of the solutions which was to fake migrate the app (accounts for me) and then re run migrations. So I did that but then this error shows up when I try to run `Python manage.py migrate`:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "accounts_profile" already exists`.

Today, I have ventured into far too much unknown territory of django and now I am in a mess which I have no idea how to solve and so I need help. I would not like to delete my database as it contains existing data and the website is also live. What do you guys recommend I should do now?

Comment: Do you have any user data in your database at all? Can you inspect your database to find out if any `auth_` tables exist?

Comment: When I tried to login to the admin using my previous superuser, I get an error page with the same error: `OperationalError at /admin/login/
no such table: auth_user`

Comment: You have faked migrations that you should have run, you'll need to fake unapply those migrations and then actually run them: `manage.py migrate auth zero --fake` then `manage.py migrate auth` for the auth app and then probably something similar for the accounts app

Comment: I tried this but now the error says: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "auth_permission" already exists`